# Decoding JSON string in PHP which has different headers

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode a series of JSON messages

The JSON messgaes are received on an adhoc basis

If the JSON messages were all exactly the same format I would be fine. However they are not.

Here is an example of two different types.

```
   object(stdClass)#11 (1) { ["SF_MSG"]=> object(stdClass)#12 (5) { ["time"]=>      string(13) "1407962618000" ["area_id"]=> string(2) "NM" ["address"]=> string(2) "2B" ["msg_type"]=> string(2) "SF" ["data"]=> string(2) "FE" } } 

   object(stdClass)#13 (1) { ["CA_MSG"]=> object(stdClass)#14 (5) { ["to"]=> string(4) "0360" ["time"]=> string(13) "1407962618000" ["area_id"]=> string(2) "WH" ["msg_type"]=> string(2) "CC" ["descr"]=> string(4) "2S30" } }
```

One has a header of SF_MSG and the other CC_MSG

My question is "How do I in PHP distinguish between the different headers so I can read them in different ways

So for example echo '$Decodedjson->SF_MSG->time;  will echo the time on the first one and 
echo $Decodedjson->CC_MSG->to; will echo the to variable. However I need to know whether the header is  SF_MSG or a CC_MSG before performing that task.

How do I read that Header title????? ie is it CC_MSG or SF_MSG   ......$Decodedjson->?????

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
              if ($con->hasFrame()){
              $msg=$con->readFrame();
              foreach (json_decode($msg->body) as $event) {

              if(isset($event['SFG_MSG'])) {
              $aid=($event->SF_MSG->area_id);
              }
              elseif(isset($event['CA_MSG'])) {
              $aid=($event->CA_MSG->area_id);
              }

              echo $aid;
```

Comment: once it's decoded it's just a php array/object/string. so yeah, you'll have to do isset() and whatnot to test and determine what "format" of message you received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json_decode() requires true as the second parameter in order for the resultant object to be an associative array.

```
foreach (json_decode($msg->body, true) as $event)
```

once you do this, $event will be an associative array and no longer an object, so you will need to change the rest of your code to access $event as an array instead of an object.

```
 // this won't work
 $aid=($event->SF_MSG->area_id);

 // change to this
 $aid = $event["SF_MSG"]["area_id"];
```

Comment: Have just put more of my code up as an EDIT. My JSON decode does not have true after it. Is that a problem?. I am currently getting a Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in...... with the above code (I have changed the CC_MSG to CA_MSG - typo in my first one)

Comment: You need to add a true as the second parameter to JSON decode in order for your code to work.

Comment: Thanks - just trying that out. Already had some success with property_exists

Comment: Great that works thanks. property_exists also worked so thanks to a previous poster and also to the people who helped me out with the isset function (Their posts seem to have disappeared from here)